# Set Java bytecode version in Android Studio for AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio, gradle

The following does not work

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

It works for the app module but not for the AppEngine (backend) module. So how do I specify target and source for the AppEngine byteCode?